Programmatically toggle sound settings in Windows
I am having issues with my sound where my 2.1 system becomes a 5.1 system according to Windows 11 and as a result I lose some channels (e.g. the voice in movies). The workaround is resetting some settings.
So I am wondering if there's a way to automate, by script perhaps, this flow as this is something I have to do every now and again (after reboot typically)? I've been trying to see if these settings are stored in the registry by recording and comparing before and after, but no success, maybe I'm doing it wrong though.
The current workaround

Right click volume icon in the notification bar
Click Sound settings
Click More sound settings
Select my playback device
Click Configure
Select something else than the selected e.g. I have 5.1 Surround so i select Stereo and go through the steps
Select the audio format i want, in my case 5.1 with just the Subwoofer as optional speaker with no full-range speakers, and go through all steps
Done

